# Cron Job problem - No such file or directory error

Tags: linux, webserver, cron

I am on shared Linux CentOS hosting with multiple domains hosted on a single account.

For one of the domains I need to run a cron job. But when I try to run that it gives me this error:

```
/bin/sh: home/abcdef/public_html/tw/tw/save.php: No such file or directory
```

Can somebody guide me how to resolve this? The cron job line is:

```
home/abcdef/public_html/tw/tw/save.php -p processqueue
```

Thanks in advance.

Vinayak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a / in front the home and you need to put php in front of the command i.e.

php path/to/php.file

see this page

http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/